# Не могу сделать действие после выбора пользователем элемента спиннера в Котлине

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Задача:
есть выпадающий список (спиннер), необходимо чтобы после выбора пользователем одного из элементов спиннера в переменную заносился её индекс и выполнялась соответствующая функция.
Кусок кода:

```
            binding.spinnerUpr1.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
            if (binding.spinnerUpr1.selectedItemPosition == 0) {
                adapterRes1(ypr17_do35)
                ypr1res = res17_do35                }
            false
        })
```

Что в итоге получается: функция активируется только при повторном выборе спиннера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам спиннер обрабатывает выбор в `OnTouchListener` и когда вы вешаете свой - он вызывается первым, поэтому в вашем случае изменение `selectedItemPosition` ещё не выполнено.
Вам нужен `OnItemSelectedListener()`:

```kotlin
binding.spinnerUpr1.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    adapterRes1(ypr17_do35)
                    ypr1res = res17_do35
                }
            }
        }
```